# Why are email replies not being forwarded properly?

Tags: civimail

When I send a bulk email through civiMail i use my email address and have the options to track replies and forward replies but in the report I see that there are 2 people who replied but the emails never got forwarded to me.

Answer (score 1):

do you see them as activities for these contacts? if you track replies, they come back to civi and get stored as activities

Comment: One was but the other wasn't.